# Can I put an if/unless clause on the next line in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

In Perl, I often find myself using the following pattern:

```perl
croak "incompatible object given: $object"
    unless $object->isa('ExampleObject') and $object->can('foo');
```

I tried to translate this into Ruby like this:

```ruby
raise ArgumentError, "incompatible object given: #{object.inspect}"
    unless object.is_a?(ExampleObject) and object.respond_to?(:foo)
```

But that does not work because Ruby interprets `unless` as the start of a new statement. As far as I understand, I can put a backslash at the end of the first line, but that looks ugly and feels wrong. I could also use a regular `unless condition raise error end` structure, but I like the style of the original form more. Is there a nice (and idiomatic) way to write this as a single statement in Ruby?

Comment: `object.is_a?(ExampleObject) and object.respond_to?(:foo) and raise ArgumentError, "incompatible object given: #{object.inspect}"`?

Comment: That defeats the purpose of putting the action in front, where it will be found faster, which is what if/unless clauses (as opposed to if/unless statements) were originally designed for.

Comment: I guess moving `unless` at the end of the first line isn't acceptable, too?

Comment: I'd say a multiline expression defeats the purpose of an inline if/unless :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I put an if/unless clause on the next line in Ruby?

You can't. From page 107 (PDF page 127) of the [final draft of ISO Ruby](https://www.ipa.go.jp/osc/english/ruby/) which usually isn't relevant, but basic things like this are and it also spares us from having to read `parse.y`:

```
unless-modifier-statement ::
    statement [no line-terminator here] unless expression
```

This is pretty clear. It just doesn't get more similar to your Perl example than:

```
raise ArgumentError, "incompatible object given: #{object.inspect}" unless
  object.is_a?(ExampleObject) and object.respond_to?(:foo)`
```

or:

```
raise ArgumentError, "incompatible object given: #{object.inspect}" \
  unless object.is_a?(ExampleObject) and object.respond_to?(:foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as you feel wrong to put a backslash at the end to force a single line statement, it is wrong to use a single line statement when it extends beyond a single line.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not really a solution, I was sloppy when reading the question. The OP wants a solution without backslash.**

You should be able to do this:

```
raise ArgumentError, "incompatible object given: #{object.inspect}" \
  unless object.is_a?(ExampleObject) and object.respond_to?(:foo)
```

The `\` characters tells ruby to keep reading as if there was no line break.

Comment: +1 because this is correct, but the OP is looking for a solution without a backslash: *"(...) I can put a backslash at the end of the first line, but that looks ugly and feels wrong"*

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know there is no other way than a `\`, since otherwise, as you already said, Ruby thinks it's a new statement.

Keep in mind that style guides and conventions differ from language to language. In Ruby I'd not expect an if/unless statement in a line coming after it's code. In fact I even dislike putting `if/unless` at the end of a line, since it reverses the reading direction from `If this, then that` to `that, if this (then what? Ah, I need to read back again)`, especially when the condition is more complex than `raise 'foo' if bar.empty?`.

In Perl and other languages though this might be different, since you have other conventions, style guides and this `;`-thingy ;)